# call another service after sending the success response in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The first controller is sending the success response after that it will call another method after sending the response.

I need to call m1()method after return the response

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/hello"}, method = POST, produces = { "application/json" })
        public Response getAllData(@RequestBody String request){

            return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello World");
        }

    public void m1(){

    }
```

Comment: Use spring aspectJ @AfterReturning advice

Comment: pls provide sample code for this

Answer (score 4):

The simple trick is to use try...finally.

```
try{
  return new Response();
} finally {
  //do after actions
}
```

'finally' will always execute after the try block no matter there is a return statement in it.

Comment: The finally block is executed before the return statement. The returned value is only stored for returning after the execution of the finally block.

Comment: m1() will call after  returning the response

Comment: @karthikmuthyam No, it won't, as I said the return value is only saved then the finally block is executed and after that the saved return value is returned. Consequently, it seems like it's executed after the return method but this is not what happens.

Answer (score 4):

Example for the Spring AspectJ using @AfterReturning advice

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class A {

  /*
   * AfterReturning advice
   */
  @AfterReturning("execution(* com.package.ClassName.getAllData(..))")
  public void m1(JoinPoint joinPoint) {


  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add @EnableAsync in your configuration class or main class
then create another service class encapsulating an Async method m1

In your class add the statement below:

```
asyncServiceImpl.m1();

@Service 
public class AsyncServiceImpl {

   @Async
   public CompletableFuture<String> m1() {
        // Your logic here
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(String.valueOf(Boolean.FALSE));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use eventListener for creating event. 
And catch it in public method with EventListener annotation.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and reliable way - run a thread. Try-final isn't good at all.
But the best solution is - throw out that SB and use pure JEE servlets to invoke all that you need (JSON, JPA, BM transactions) in the client's request's thread, so you will never get stuck like that.